# How should I go building login serializer & View which uses DRF for Token Authentication?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is how my Signup Serializer looks like

```
class AuthUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'role')
    
    def create(self, data):
        return AuthUser.objects.create(**data)
```

Here is the view of it:

```
class Signup(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthUserSerializer
    queryset = AuthUser.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.instance)
        return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

And data is getting inserted in DATA successfully, and token is being generated properly. Now I want to make login endpoint where user will enter his email and password and if true return the token. Kindly assist me, on how should I go building this login serializer & view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to do it? DRF provides full authentication model and you don't need to build it by yourself. If you want customize it, use inheritance.

in **settings.py** define auth classes (in your case, use TokenAuthentication)

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

in **urls.py** add auth url:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

If you want to customize authentication, inherit from DRF ObtainTokenAuth:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

and then change your **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view())
]
```

Read more in DRF documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. The only problem is I removed username from default USER Model of django. What I want is to customise this CustomAuthToken view to take email & password as input, and return the token!!